# Render Border constraining model in all viewport shading modes except Rendered

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

Quite new to Blender. I'm using 2.75 and was working on this lamp (part of a Udemy course). I was using the Render Border tool (Ctrl+B) to constrain rendering to part of the model and somewhere in amongst cancelling/redrawing that and moving the camera around my file now only displays a minimal part of my model in both Object and Edit modes when using anything except Rendered Shading (see images).

I got to that point where I'd pressed a bunch of keys and couldn't remember quite what I'd done, couldn't undo it etc. It looks like a bug to me tbh, but if anyone knows which shortcut I may have pressed to limit the viewport like this I'd appreciate it!

If there is anyway to host the .blend file somewhere if anyone wanted to take a look, then please let me know.

[image: Lamp in Object View / Solid Shading]
[image: Lamp in Object View / Rendered Shading]

Comment: Try using Alt+B

Comment: Thanks @Denis - this was the correct answer, thank you. Context for anyone else that finds themselves here: I had apparently enabled the 'Clipping border' -  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html
The question I have duplicated also has the correct solution for this problem - my question is a dupe because I simply didn't know what I was describing (hence thinking it might be a bug!). Thanks all.